# What queries should you run to debug what are the stored procedures that caused a deadlock and on what line I should look at on MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

What queries should you run to debug what are the stored procedures that caused a deadlock and on what line I should look at on MSSQL? I am trying to fix a recurring deadlock on MSSQL. The issue is I am not sure what queries I should run to get all the information I need.

Comment: [sp_BlitzLock](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/main/sp_BlitzLock.sql)

Comment: A XEvent trace to capture the deadlock graph would be immensely useful, as would the query plan, relevant tables and indexes, and obviously the queries involved (the deadlock graph will tell you most of what you need to find the right ones)

Answer (score 0):

You can add code to the stored procedures to output progress to the Messages window as each step starts and completes.

```
DECLARE @strStatus VARCHAR(200);
SET @strStatus = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE()) + ' Starting sp1...';
RAISERROR (@strStatus, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

EXEC sp1

SET @strStatus = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE()) + ' Finished sp1...';
RAISERROR (@strStatus, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could capture deadlock details,

1. Following trace flags would write complete deadlock details to SQL Server
   error log,

```
DBCC TRACEON (1204, -1)
DBCC TRACEON (1222, -1)
```

2. Setup extended events session to capture details,

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Deadlock_Capture] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlos.scheduler_monitor_deadlock_ring_buffer_recorded,
ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_deadlock,
ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_deadlock_chain,
ADD EVENT sqlserver.xml_deadlock_report
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer(SET max_events_limit=(10),max_memory=(131072))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO
```

3. My least preferred option is using SQL Profiler, capturing these event classes `Lock: Deadlock Chain` and `Deadlock graph`.

Using approaches 1 and 2 you would see deadlock information like here,

[Approach 01 from SQL error log.](https://pastebin.com/zFv4Z4vH)

[Approach 02 from Extended events ring buffer.](https://pastebin.com/svzvXhTf)

You may find the queries in either of those files which I have used to simulate deadlock.

Comment: Date,Source,Severity,Message
01/04/2022 16:26:27,spid29s,Unknown,deadlock victim=process2b39fabdc28
01/04/2022 16:26:27,spid29s,Unknown,deadlock-list
01/04/2022 16:26:27,spid5s,Unknown,Deadlock encountered .... Printing deadlock information
01/04/2022 16:26:22,spid37s,Unknown,deadlock victim=process2b0ad4668c8
01/04/2022 16:26:22,spid37s,Unknown,deadlock-list
01/04/2022 16:26:22,spid5s,Unknown,Deadlock encountered .... Printing deadlock information

Comment: The logs I am getting are useless.

Comment: @ak12 Not sure which approach you have tried, but I have posted two sample results using approaches 01 & 02 by simulating deadlock. Check my edited post.